# como puedo sacar el promedio de tres calificaciones de un alumno?

Tags: php

Solo necesito sacar el promedio del alumno los datos estan en una base de datos MYSQL  la pagina esta hecha en php, como podria promediar las celdas (calificaciones) en una celda promedio?en este codigo segun yo estoy ejecutando el promedio. Pero no me sale nada

```
<B>PROMEDIO:
          <input type='text' name='promedio' value="<?php echo @$promedio->promedio?>">
          <br>         


          <?
             @$gramatica = $_POST['gramatica'];
             @$matematicas = $_POST['matematicas'];
             @$historia = $_POST['historia'];

             @$promedio = ($gramatica + $matematicas + $historia)/3;


          ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [so], te invito a que realices el [tour] y revises [ask]. Deberias [edit] la pregunta y añadir mas información, como el codigo del formulario. Puedes revisar tambien [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema te viende de que primero imprimes la variable $promedio vacía y después haces el cálculo. Tendrías que hacer el cálculo por encima de la etiqueta.

```
<?
                 @$gramatica = $_POST['gramatica'];
                 @$matematicas = $_POST['matematicas'];
                 @$historia = $_POST['historia'];

                 @$promedio = ($gramatica + $matematicas + $historia)/3;


              ?>
    <B>PROMEDIO:
              <input type='text' name='promedio' value="<?php echo @$promedio?>">
              <br>
```